# laravel factories inside nwidart modules

Tags: laravel, laravel-factory

I'm trying to use a laravel factory inside module.

I call factory inside controller like this

```
$ar_reference = factory(ArReference::class)->create();
```

This is my factory.

```
use App\Models\ArReference;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(ArReference::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    return [
        'reference_no' => 'My Ar'
    ];
});
```

I call the factory like this inside my module ServiceProvider **ArServiceProvider** inside **registerFactories()** function like this.

```
public function registerFactories() {

        $this->app->singleton(Factory::class, function () {
            return Factory::construct(__DIR__ . '/Database/factories');
        });
}
```

But unfortunately I'm getting this error

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::construct()
>   must be an instance of Faker\Generator, string given, called in
>   /var/www/Modules/Ar/Providers/ArServiceProvider.php on line 94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass Faker generator in the first argument, see: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.html#method_construct

```
return Factory::construct(\Faker\Factory::create(), __DIR__ . '/Database/factories');
```